# access html content through CSS?

Tags: html, css-selectors, css

```
<div id=menu>
 <ul>
  <li class="section-title">auto-text1</li>
  <li class="section-title">auto-text2</li>
  <li class="section-title">auto-text3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

How can I give special treatment to auto-text3 through css?

Answer (score 3):

See section 6.6.5.7. of the CSS3 - future - proposal:

**:last-child pseudo-class**

Same as :nth-last-child(1). The :last-child pseudo-class represents an element that is the last child of some other element.

```
ul > li:last-child { }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo

(In your example `</menu>` probably is meant to be the closing `</div>`.)

For the time being I guess it's still best to use classes marking the first and last list element, or simple Javascript on your #menu id.

Comment: Keep in mind that last-child browser support is wanting: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo):

```
#menu > ul > li.section-title:nth-of-type(3)
```

This will select the third element of all `li` elements with the class *section-title*.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the other answers, there aren’t (currently) any CSS selectors that let you select an element based on its content.

Comment: If I need to select an element based on its content ? I need to use jquery/client-side scripting tools ?